# Encode PNG images to MP4

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, ffmpeg.js

I'm using [FFMPEG.js](https://github.com/ffmpegjs/ffmpeg.js) to convert PNG images into MP4 in the Browser with this code:

```
    const { createWorker } = FFmpeg;
    const worker = createWorker({
        corePath: 'ffmpeg-core.min.js',
        progress: (p) => console.log(p),
        logger: ({ message }) => console.log(message),
    });
    const image2video = async (frames) => {
        console.log('Loading ffmpeg-core.min.js');
        await worker.load();
        console.log('Loading data');

        const d = new Date();
        const timestamp = d.getTime();

        for(let i = 0; i < frames.length; i += 1) {
            const num = `00${i}`.slice(-3);
            const fileName = `tmp.${timestamp}.${num}.png`;
            console.log(fileName);
            await worker.write(fileName, frames[i]); // base64 'image/png'
            const { file } = await worker.read(fileName);
            // throws -> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined
            const testFile = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([file.buffer], { type: 'image/png' }));
            console.log(testFile);
        }
        await worker.run('-framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i /data/*.png -c:a copy -shortest -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4', { output: 'out.mp4' });
        const { data } = await worker.read('out.mp4');
        const outputURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'video/mp4' }));
        console.log(outputURL);
    }
```

However it throws:

```
[png @ 0x1175980] Warning: not compiled with thread support, using thread emulation
[image2 @ 0x1177180] Could not open file : /data/*.png
[image2 @ 0x1177180] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: png, none(pc)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, image2, from '/data/*.png':
Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: png, none(pc), 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

What could be missing here?

Comment: instead of /data/*.png try only *.png

Comment: Tried that, and since even at `const { file } = await worker.read(fileName);` it throws error so must be something wrong that it would not "persist" the image/frame

Comment: have you seen https://github.com/ffmpegjs/ffmpeg.js/blob/master/examples/browser/image2video.html